# nodemon auto reload not working with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:8.11.2-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps alpine-sdk python \
    && npm install --production --silent \
    && apk del .build-deps
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["nodemon","-L","/app/app.js" ]
```

I'm running it in a docker-compose.

I've tried the legacy flag but to no avail.

this is my docker-compose.yml, It's not using any volumes

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - redis
      - db
```

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in /app/app.js, but with this information is not possible to figure it out. Could you post your `docker logs` output and/or your app.js?

Comment: app.js has no issue as I can run nodemon correctly outside docker-compose. And also there's no error. I get nodemon message `[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node .`` but its not doing reload when Im making changes. Maybe volumes issue?

Comment: How are you making these changes? If you do that in host and haven't mounted volume, you won't see changes in container.

Comment: How can I mount the volume? I'm making my changes locally where dockerfile etc reside.